# I am trying to make a big string from a JavaScript Array using join() function is it possible to include html with that if possible

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a big string from a JavaScript Array using join() function is it possible to include html with that if possible how I will do that ?

```
var htmltext= ["text1", "text", "new text"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = htmltext.join()
```

Comment: `where i will add html` where you need it

Comment: Please show us the expected output, it's not clear from your question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include **html** in your **array** and use `join` function to merge them. Because the join method joins all array elements into a string a separator can be provided that will be placed between every item. This separator can be anything from plain strings to html.

```js
var yourArray = ["<h1>What is Lorem Ipsum? </h1>", "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s", "<h1>Why do we use it? </h1>", "t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout."];
alert(yourArray.join( '<br> COmmon html <br>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add html as you added string there.

**HTML**

```
<div id ="demo"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
 var html1 = "<h1>Hello </h1>";
 var html2 = "<h2>Hello </h2>";
 var html3 = "<h3>Hello </h3>";

 var htmltext= [html1, html2, html3];
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = htmltext.join()
```